# Focus input in Cordova web app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

Asked a question about this earlier. Have tried a new method, still doesn't work. I have a button that removes a `<p>` element and replaces it with a `<textarea>` with the same content, but editable. I need to tranfer focus to that `<textarea>`, but cannot on device, only on browser. I have added the requiered `<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiersUserAction" value="false"/>` propery to `config.xml`.

HTML:

```
<div ng-click="edit()">
  Click here to edit
</div>

<div ng-if="!post.typing" class="post-text">
  <p>{{post.post_text}}</p>
</div>

<div ng-if="post.typing" class="post-text">
  <form ng-submit="submit()">
    <textarea id="text"  ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && submit()" style="width:100%" ng-model="post.post_text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; width: 1px; height: 1px;"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.edit = function() {
  $scope.post.typing = true;
  $timeout(function () {
    document.getElementById("text").focus();
  }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I note in your comment you included:

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiersUserAction" value="false"/>
```

in config.xml. There is a typo in Requires - this may be your issue!

Comment: That's probably it, oops. That project is over now, so I'll just assume that was it and accept.